# Having trouble with the space settings on copy location bone constraint

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

So I used to know how to set up the copy location constraint so the bone using it would move when the target moved relative to its own location, but could still move in t's own space. Now I'm trying to do that in 2.91 but it can't seem to get it to work anymore.
What I'm trying to do it have a pole target that has no parent but has copy location on an empty which is parented to to the target bone of the inverse kinematic constraint. That way the pole target moves with the IK target but it doesn't affect the IK of the leg unless moved in it's own space.
How do I do this?

Comment: it should work, where does it fail for you? Also, why do you copy the empty location rather than directly the IK target?

Comment: Well I can make the pole target follow the owner of the constraint but it can more on it's own. It's stuck to the owner, And other settings I have tried move the pole target way beneath the owner.

Comment: I tried constraining the pole target to the IK target, and it didn't work so well. When I moved the target up the Pole moved in an opposite diagonal direction